# Is there any better way to handle GCD credentials than using private key file?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I would like to use the google cloud datastore from Android, so I would not have to set up cloud endpoints et al. Trying the snapshot 1.0.0 libs, the only way to add credentials seems to be via a file name to the private key file. That does not sound right for Android, is there some better way, ideally with an Android example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the AccountManager for identity management and authentication storage, see https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android.

You should be able to use the [Oauth2 flow](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Android) to get the appropriate credentials, and just pass that in to the DatastoreOptions.

Note that the Cloud Datastore API does not support fine grain ACLs, so the user will have to be an admin of your Project in order to access the API.